# PHP Copy, failed to open stream: Connection refused

Tags: php

i am trying to copy a image, it is hosted here, this is just an example:

```
http://111.74.239.161:8898/uploads/allimg/130821/2-130R1100341.jpg
```

I want to copy the image, but i keep getting connection refused. What could be the root of this error ?

What strikes me as odd is that its using port 8898 ?

Comment: I have tried, file_get_contents and copy, but are returning the same error

Comment: Check your firewall rules.

Comment: I've tried code: `<?php
$file = "http://111.74.239.161:8898/uploads/allimg/130821/2-130R1100341.jpg";
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile($file);` - and it works on my local webserver, so, you have one of the problems: 1) Your server's firewall blocks outgoing connections to port #8898, or 2) The target server has your IP in it's blacklist

Comment: @MihanEntalpo: Or 3) Your server's firewall is blocking connections to that IP, with a blacklist perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can view the image in a browser that is on the same machine as your program, then it might be that the server won't send the picture unless you look like a user rather than a program. In that case, modifying the browser identification string might fix your problem.

If you cannot view the image from a browser running on the program's PC, you will need to look elsewhere for the source of your problem.